# JavaScript, onclick-event not responding

Tags: javascript, onclick, member

I hope to get a simple and straight answer as this is driving me crazy. I know this isn't the best way of doing this but I just can't figure out, why these two lines behave differently:

First line, working fine:

```
<img id="hellig_del42736" src="../images/kryds.png" title="Slet helligdagen den 01-01-2017..." alt="Slet helligdagen den 01-01-2017..." onclick="if(confirm('Vil du slette helligdagen den 01-01-2017?')){document.getElementById('helligid42736').style.textDecoration='line-through';hasChanged=false;window.location.href='/admin/admin.asp?vacfrom='+(25569+(new Date(document.getElementById('feriefra').value).getTime()/1000/86400))+'&delbankhd=42736&page=2&sid=feriefra'}" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onmouseout="this.style.cursor=''">
```

Second line, not responding - sometimes resulting in "member not found-error" - sometimes works if debugging (F12) is open:

```
<img id="blockedip_del8" src="../images/kryds.png" title="Fjern blokeringen af IP# 5.6.7.8 (mail@mail.dk)..." onclick="if(confirm('Vil du fjerne blokeringen af IP# 5.6.7.8 (mail@mail.dk)?')){document.getElementById('blockid8').style.textDecoration='line-through';hasChanged=false;window.location.href='/admin/admin.asp?delblockedip={93F17D3B-7FA1-48F1-8792-K52E30273818}&page=5&sid=deadlinetime'}" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onmouseout="this.style.cursor=''">
```

I have tried several thing inside the comfirm()-statement (second line):

- Removed paranthesis with no difference
- Removed hashtag with no difference
- Ensured that there are no conflicting id's

These lines are to my best knowledge codewise identical yet they behave differently.

I know I can put all the statements in a function and that "I really shouldn't..." but if this is how I want it, how can I fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: What the? Aren't the two URLs having different parameters for the GET request?

Comment: There must be something else wrong. Both lines work fine AFAICT.

Comment: The two URL''s have different parameters but the commands are equal as such. It's strange because both lines should work fine but does not. I have checked the surrounding code and nothing is wrong and nothing is reported besides the occasional "member not found". Can anyone explain why the code works if it's run with the debugger?

Comment: In Chrome I get "Uncaught TypeError: confirm is not a function" which seems strange. If I replace - if(confirm('...')) - with - alert('...') - everything is fine...

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot!

For some idiotic reason I had used id="confirm" on a form element within the same form and changing that reserved word to id="confirmation" solved everything.

I thought I checked everything but I hadn't. Only removing elements one by one and testing led to the error.

Thanks "idmean" for pointing me to the surrounding code.